# Consulta cantidad de veces que se repite cada dato de una columna en Laravel

Tags: laravel-6

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$join = DB::table('clasificaciones')->join('tabla1','clasificaciones.id','=','tabla1.idcategoria')
                    ->select('clasificaciones.*','tabla1.*')
                    ->where("tabla1.idusuario",$iduser)
                    ->where("tabla1.fechacumplimiento",">", 0)
                    ->pluck('clasificaciones');
```

Que me entrega como ejemplo los siguientes datos:

- Clasificacion1
- Clasificacion2
- Clasificacion3
- Clasificacion3
- Clasificación2
- Clasificación2
- Clasificación1
- Clasificación4

Como pueda hacer para que me entregue la cantidad de cada clasificación ordenada, es decir:

- Clasificación1 se repite 2 veces
- Clasificación2 se repite 3 veces
- Clasificación3 se repite 2 veces
- Clasificación4 se repite 1 vez

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿El primer grupo de resultados viene de clasificaciones o de tabla1?

Comment: Puedes perfectamente usar una función de agregación como **COUNT(*)** posteriormente agrupar por todas las demás columnas y te regresará cuantas veces aparece cada una de esas clasificaciones

Comment: El resultado viene de la tabla1 que cada fila tiene una clasificación. Las clasificaciones las define el usuario y se almacenan en la tabla clasificaciones y se relaciona con la tabla1 a través del id de la clasificación.

Comment: Gracias BetaM. Finalmente utilice la función  array_count_values ($matriz) que entrega la clasificación y la cantidad de veces que se repite.

Comment: Publicala como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Utilice la función **array_count_values** que entrega el total existente de cada clasificación en este caso luego de la consulta agregue:

```
$matriz=array();
$matriz=json_decode($join);
$resultado= array_count_values ($matriz);
return $resultado;
```

Lo que entrega como resultado la clasificación y la cantidad de veces que se repite en la columna de la tabla:

```
{"Clasificacion1": 2,"Clasificacion2": 3,"Clasificacion3": 2,"Clasificacion4": 1}
```